# how to check that specific vector exist in list of vectors in java?

Tags: java

I have list of vectors of bits(0 and 1) and I want to check that specific vector of bits exist in that list. I used this code but the answer not correct.

```
if(bitset2.contains(bi))
    System.out.println("data found in file");         
else
    System.out.println("data not found in files ");
```

`bitset2` represent list of vectors of bits and `bi` is the vector of bits.

this code always print `data not found in files` although the vector exists in list and the condition is verified.

Comment: can you share your vector of bit and your list please, how fill it?

Comment: be.tarsos.lsh.Vector bitset1 = new be.tarsos.lsh.Vector (675); 
    for(int n=0;n<vec1.size();n++){
    int asci_of_a=(int)'a';
    String l=vec1.get(n);
   char[]c=l.toCharArray();
   int first=((int)c[0]-asci_of_a)*26;
   int second= (int)c[1]-asci_of_a;
   int index=first+second;
   bitset1.set(index,(int)1.0);
 }
    System.out.println(bitset1);

bitset2.add(bitset1); @YCF_L

Comment: Can you edit that into the question, and also explain how your custom "vector"class works

Comment: you have to edit your question instead

Comment: (Sounds like Vector is not a custom class, but from TarsosLSH)

Answer (score 0):

You have loop throw your List and use `.equals` to check if your Vector exist in your List or not, for example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vector vec1 = new Vector(3);
    vec1.add(0, 0);
    vec1.add(1, 1);
    vec1.add(2, 0);
    Vector vec2 = new Vector(3);
    vec2.add(0, 0);
    vec2.add(1, 1);
    vec2.add(2, 0);

    //create a List of Vectors
    List<Vector> bitset2 = new ArrayList<>();
    bitset2.add(vec2);

    boolean exist = false;
    //Loop throw your List and check if your vector exist or no
    for (Vector vector : bitset2) {
        if (vector.equals(vec1)) {
            exist = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(exist ? "data found in file" : "data not found in file");
}
```

Comment: thank you, but what Arrays here mean in if(Arrays.equals(b,bi)). @YCF_L

Comment: @shereensaleh `Arrays.equals` will compare between two arrays it will return true if all your values are equal, else it will return false

Comment: its appear that no suitable method for Arrays.equal(vector,vector).@YCF_L

Comment: @shereensaleh ok in your case you have to use `vector1.contains(vector2)` this is how you can compare two vector, but don't with a loop

Comment: @shereensaleh what you have exactly did you have a type like this : `Vector<byte[]> bitset2 = new Vector<>();` or what exactly ?

Comment: for ( be.tarsos.lsh.Vector b : bitset2) {
    if (b.equals( bi)) {
        out1=data+"  Data  Found In File:-  "+file+"\n";  
    } 
           else
    
                  out1=data+"  Data not Found In File:-  "+file+"\n"; 
}@YCF_L

Comment: appear the same problem data not found in files . @YCF_L

Comment: @shereensaleh not `b.equals(bi)` it is `Arrays.equals(b, bi)` you have to import this library `import java.util.Arrays;` ok

Comment: this method not suitable Arrays.equals(vector,vector).@YCF_L

Comment: @shereensaleh can you please show me your definition of `be.tarsos.lsh.Vector` how it look like ?

Comment: a vector of 'dimension' values contain 0 and 1 @ YCF_L

Comment: be.tarsos.lsh.Vector bitset1 = new be.tarsos.lsh.Vector (675); 
        for(int n=0;n<vec1.size();n++){
        int asci_of_a=(int)'a';
        String l=vec1.get(n);
       char[]c=l.toCharArray();
       int first=((int)c[0]-asci_of_a)*26;
       int second= (int)c[1]-asci_of_a;
       int index=first+second;
       bitset1.set(index,(int)1.0);
     }@YCF_L

Comment: @shereensaleh how `bi` look like?

Comment: the previous comment is the bitset1 , i mistype bi.@YCF_L

Comment: i want to check if bit vector bitset1 exist in list of bit vectors bitset2.@YCF_L

Comment: @shereensaleh check my edit i think i understand what you want ;)